# Exporting a service from an NgModule with forRoot

Tags: angular

I have created a module @foo/bar

`static forRoot() : ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: BarModule,
        providers: [BarService]
}`

I can import from my AppModule

`import { BarModule } from '@foo/bar' 
 ...
 imports: [BarModule.forRoot()}`

However, how do I actually use the BarService in a component? Simply importing like this does not get me access to BarService, as I hoped:

`import { BarService } from '@foo/bar' // Compile error: there is no BarService`

Comment: Where is `BarService` defined? You want to import `BarService` from where it's defined not `@foo/bar`

Comment: Please try to reproduce in stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

**`BarService`**  is not same as **`BarModule`**, it should have a different location to be imported from.

If you are using VSCode you can just import it using the IDE. check the path from where you import is right!

then consume it inside the constructor as follows,

```
export class YourComponent{
  constuctor(privatr bar:BarService){
    console.log(this.bar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the service you need to inject it

```
export class MyComponenr {
  constuctor(privatr bar:BarService){
    console.log(bar.someprop);
  }
}
```

For this to work, you also need the import you already have.